# Electron Js: Unable to install using .msi because the path is too long

Tags: node.js, npm, windows-installer, electron, npm-install

I have created a package of electron application by using `electron-packager` and created MSI project using Visual studio setup project.

**Problem**

While installing the application I am getting the following error:

[image]

I just cannot rename the file or change the location as its a part of node modules.

Please help and suggest what should I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to package your app into an archive by passing the [`asar`](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager/blob/v7.0.1/usage.txt#L20) option to `electron-packager`, that will allow you to avoid the path limit issues and speed up your app startup on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

unless you run latest, you should update node and npm, then rebuild the package.

In npm@3 they worked about that specific issue to flatten the dependency storage folders as much as possible.

Comment: Actually i have installed npm and node a week ago so it must be the latest.

Comment: can you show their versions ? Can you show your package json dependencies ?